# The package requires NuGet client version '3.6.0' or above

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I want to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and its component. I am using Visual Studio 2015 with NuGet Client version previously 3.5.0 and now I have 3.6.0-rtm-2511 (which is the latest) downloaded from https://www.nuget.org/downloads as instructed by error report. I don't know why issue still persist that I need to have 3.6.0 or higher.

How to update my NuGet Package Manager in other way?
I can't find my Nuget Package Manager for Visual Studio in Update from Tools > Extension and Updates > Updates > Visual Studio Gallery.
I can only see it in Tools > Extension and Updates > Installed but there is no update for it but I noticed that 'Automatically update this extension' is checked.

**Result from PM Console**

```
PM> install-package microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver  
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver/index.json  
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver/index.json 329ms  
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.1' from 'nuget.org'.  
Install failed. Rolling back...  
Uninstalling NuGet package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.2.1.1.  
Executing nuget actions took 162.34 ms  
install-package : The 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.1' package requires NuGet client version '3.6.0' or above, but the current NuGet 
version is '3.6.0-rtm-2511'. To upgrade NuGet, please go to http://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget  
At line:1 char:1  
+ install-package microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver  
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Time Elapsed: 00:00:33.0573364
```

Comment: You can download Nuget.Exe latest versions from https://www.nuget.org/downloads

Comment: It's the same with the link I provided yet I tried to downlload and install, and it says 'This extension is already installed to all applicable products'. In which, it is the 3.6.0-rtm-2511. It is not recognized as higher than 3.6.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The package requires NuGet client version '3.6.0' or above

This is a known issue about nuget. NuGet team fixed it for Nuget 4 which comes with VS2017, but 2015 users are left behind.

Ticket: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6403

Besides, NuGet team will consider a fix. At this time there are no plans to release a new version of NuGet for VS 2015.

So if you want to use the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.1`, you have to update your Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2017. Or if the lower version of this package is acceptable to you, you can use the version **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0.3**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the files:

- %userprofile%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore\3.1.8\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.nuspec
- %userprofile%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.abstractions\3.1.8\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.abstractions.nuspec
- %userprofile%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers\3.1.8\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers.nuspec
- %userprofile%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational\3.1.8\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational.nuspec
- %userprofile%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\3.1.8\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools.nuspec

Change line 3 from:

`<metadata minClientVersion="3.6">`

to:

`<metadata minClientVersion="3.6.0-rtm-2511">`

Now go back to the Package Manager Console and try the install again:

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the package from Nuget Package Manager (**Manage NuGet Packages**)and not from console. The package manager will provide you option to update your NUGET application. Look in the **'Visual Studio Gallery'** section of the **'Extension and Updates'** window that pops up.

Comment: This won't work, my version is currently 3.4 and shows that there are no updated available.